# White vertices still present in render of image

Tags: rendering, texturing, vertices, reflection

I'm new to Blender, but I've managed to set up and render a scene. However, I can't seem to overcome one small quibble: upon rendering, there are white nodes/vertices left despite having a material applied to them, as seen here:
[image]

To be honest, I'm not sure if it's some strange reflection occuring, but I'd assume the reason comes from the fact that the models in the render have been imported from models I had made in Inventor (as STL files). The flat plane with image applied has had 'glossy' ray visibility disabled to avert any weird reflection issues. I have applied edge modifiers and surface modifiers to no avail. Lastly, the overall half-cylinder mesh is shaded with two separate materials on the same model. I am using the Cycles renderer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated to understand where this is coming from!

Comment: Hello :). This looks like an interesting problem. Could you please [share the .Blend file?](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)